# Multiple Chromecast App Dev Keys on single HTML?

Tags: google-cast

We are working on Chromecast integration into our app. The development agency has one Chromecast and we have one here in office. Both have been whitelisted using the same HTML reciever.

Our agency is sending us test versions (with our App key), but the App is not recognizing our Chromecast (in iOS and Android).

We are guessing that there is an issue with possible multiple app keys running off of the same receiver html?

or

The serial number we provided is incorrect?

## Google-cast

Comment: I have an app with two different receivers and it works fine with the same app id. When white listing the second device I made sure to put in the application my existing app id. I also explained it in the comments, not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible to have multiple devices using the same App Key, just [register the additional devices](https://developers.google.com/cast/whitelisting) and mention the prior key.  If there is a problem you can write us at Chromecast-updates@google.com

Comment: Any chance you could respond to the comment I posted on one of your answers? With all due respect, if StackOverflow is the only Chromecast / Google-Cast Community forum then it's actually pretty poor. There are two open questions (one with a bounty I posted) asking about MPEG2-TS and MPEG-DASH. It would be nice if you could at least answer one of them. Sorry, but I have no other way of contacting anyone in the Chromecast development program and it's very frustrating to have little / no support.